# SQL setup for searching

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to search various manufacturers by selecting checkboxes, how would I do this?

What if they choose 7 to search how would i get it to work with the sql string right now i have to enter it manually like this `LIKE '%BMW'` but I want it to come from the loop:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
        echo $selected."</br>";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Cars` WHERE `manufacturer` LIKE '%BMW' OR 
        `manufacturer` LIKE '%Audi' ORDER BY `tier` ASC";
```

Comment: build your sql dynamically. and consider using a better table structure so you're not stuck using unindexable/unoptimizable sub-string matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you're narrowing using checkboxes, like in Amazon for instance, they aren't going to be using wildcards. In this case, you would probably be better doing `WHERE IN` for a list of manufacturers.

```
SELECT * FROM `Cars` 
WHERE `manufacturer` IN ('BMW', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'Lexus', 'Cadillac', 'Huffy Bikes');
```

In this case, to use in a PDO prepared statement, you don't need a loop.  Just array_fill and implode() to generate the placeholders and then bind the array in execute().

```
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($_POST['check_list']), '?');
$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `Cars` WHERE `manufacturer` IN ('.implode(',' $placeholders).')');
$stmt->execute($_POST['check_list']);
```

If you have *Audi* and *BMW* in `$_POST['check_list']`, the `implode(',', $placeholders)` will output `?,?` and **pdo::execute()** will bind each placeholder (`?`) with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the name of the manufacturers in the $_POST['check_list'] array.

You could simply concatenate that name into a variable and use it to build your query. To build the query, the easy way is to use the IN operator, instead of the like operator.
The code should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Cars` WHERE `manufacturer` IN (".implode(",",$_POST['check_list']).")";
```

This should work, but create a security issue (sql injection).
To do the thing in the right way, you should use an array, with the manufacturers name and an id for each, like:

```
$manufacturers = array( 1 => "BMW", 3 => "Renault", 4 => "Ferrari");
```

And you could create the checkbox dinamically from this array:

```
foreach($manufacturers as $id => $name) {
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="'.$id.'>'.$name.'</label>';
}
```

And than, in the query part, you have to cycle to the $_POST['check_list'] (that now contains the numeric id) and assign to a temporary array, the manufacturers name you need to insert into the query

```
$manif_to_select = array();
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $manif_id) {
    if(!isset($manufacturers[$manif_id]))
        continue;

    $manif_to_select[] = $manufacturers[$manif_id];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Cars` WHERE `manufacturer` IN (".implode(",",$manif_to_select).")";
```

Comment: You would need to use input `name="check_list[]"`, but I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injections.

Comment: edited (thx for the fix... This append when you write  speedly)
Yes, I can use the prepared statement to prevent sql injection... but a user still can try to send value that are not in the database (that is not a security issue, but can create other issue...) 
in this way you can also use non unicode name etc...

Comment: Why can't i use two $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Cars` WHERE manufacturer IN ('". implode("','", $checklist) . ") AND tier IN (". implode("','", $tier) . "')";

Comment: @youngkid7, that query is at risk of SQL injections because you are using user input directly in the query.  Someone could inject SQL code in there to manipulate or destroy your database.  You should always use prepared statements with mysqli or pdo for queries with user input ($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, etc)